# function to print linked list in reverse order

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I was searching on how can I print a reverse of linked list and I found this piece of code

```
/* Function to reverse the linked list */
void printReverse(struct node* head)
{
    // Base case  
    if (head == NULL)
       return;

    // print the list after head node
    printReverse(head->next);

    // After everything else is printed, print head
    printf("%d  ", head->data);
}
```

The problem is that I do not understand the part where it reaches the last pointer which points to NULL and how it comes back one by one and prints the linked list in reverse order.

Is the return statement what makes it go step by step back? Or something else? Please help because I do not understand.

Comment: You need to look into how recursion works.

Comment: There's an implicit `return;` immediately before the `}` at the end of the function.  After the data is printed, the function returns.  In the case when the node is NULL, it returns without printing anything, of course.

Comment: A `LIFO` structured linked list might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recursive function. Recursive functions work by pushing variables onto the execution stack. The execution order pops off the stack in reverse order from the order it was pushed on the stack. This means that the last execution prints first, then the one previous to that, and so forth until all executions of printReverse print their values.

Comment: ...and better to convert to tail recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function; that is to say, it calls itself.

Let's use the sequence `example` as your example data:

When you first run the function, it's pointing at the head, and the head is the item containing the data `e`. It has a `next` property, which is the item containing the data `x`. Therefore, `head == NULL` evaluates `False` and the `if` statement doesn't fire.

The function then calls a second copy of itself, pointing to the next item in the list - the item containing `x`. This has a `next` property, which is the item containing `a`. The function then calls a third copy of itself with this item, and so on and so forth until it hits the final `e`, and calls a copy of itself with the `next` property of that item - that is to say, it calls itself with `NULL` as the input.

This copy of the function then `return`s due to the `if` statement- crucially, it `return`s to the function that called it, in this case the copy of itself the level above. This copy then carries on where it left off, executing `printf("%d  ", head->data);` - in this case, it prints an `e`. Then it falls out of the body of the function and so `return`s to the function that called it. This copy of the function will have a `head->data` value of `l`, and this will print as above. As such, it then runs through back up the chain until it gets to the original function call, prints the first `e`, and then returns to the function that called it.

Hope this makes sense, I know it's not the best or most elegant explanation of recursion but there's a lot of material out there if this is confusing explaining exactly how recursion works and how useful it can be!

Answer (score 0):

The thing that makes it go in reverse is *to have the `printf()` call **after** the recursive call to itself*.

You can try interchanging the two calls as in

```
void printNormal(struct node* head)
{
    // Base case  
    if (head == NULL)
       return;

    // Before all, we print this node info.
    printf("%d  ", head->data);

    // print the rest of the list after this node
    printReverse(head->next);

}
```

And you'll get the forward printing of the list.

The mission of the so commented *Base case* is to avoid infinite recursion.  The end of the list is special, we can do the check on entering the `printReverse()` function, so we can deal with the special case of an empty list, or we have to do it at each call (then we should put a check before calling the function inside it, and in the code that calls the recursive function (better to put it at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

As others have already explained the recursive version. I suggest you to have a look at this iterative version of printing linked list in reverse order. This is more easy to understand and implement as compared to recursive version, however it increases time complexity.

```
    // To ease testing of code here linked list is created randomly of given size.
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<time.h>
    #define size 10 //Size of list
    struct node
    {
          int info;
          struct node * next;
    };
    typedef struct node* Node;       
    Node start;
    int main()
    {
       int i;
       srand(time(NULL));
       for(i=0;i<size;i++)
       {
          Node ptr;
          ptr=(Node)malloc(sizeof(node));
          ptr->info=rand()%100; //random list is created of given size.
          ptr->next=NULL;
          if(start==NULL)
              start=ptr;
          else
          {
               ptr->next=start;
               start=ptr;
          }
    }
    printf(" Traversal of Linked List in forward direction -\n");
    Node temp=start;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d ",temp->info);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n Traversal of Linked List in backward direction -\n");
    Node ptr=NULL;
    while(ptr!=start)
    {
        temp=start;
        while(temp->next!=ptr)
        temp=temp->next;
        printf(" %d ",temp->info);
        ptr=temp;
    }
       return 0;
    }
```

For more details visit-
https://github.com/SahdevKansal02/Data-Structures-And-Algorithms.git

Answer (score -1):

Jim Rodgers hits the nail on the head. However, you could make life very easy for yourself by having a doubly linked list.

So for example your entry (node) has both a previous and next member pointing to the previous entry and next entry respectively. Then you don't need more "obfuscated" code than necessary.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the sense of the question.  The SO wants to understand why it works that way and how to do in the opposite direction, and you are blaming about some programming customs that are far of being of interest here (or even useful).

Comment: LOL! So in the context of singly linked list (and its reversal), some friendly advice as to the use of the natural alternative, the doubly linked list, is of no use. BTW, when you need to reverse search or indeed swap entries in a linked list, the doubly linked data structure is the advised option in cases where memory is not severely limited. BTW, I like the way you think I was talking about a "custom" rather than a data structure.

Comment: reLOL! the exercise was about recursive function calls, and not on double linked lists. I know a double linked list allows you to traverse it either direction, but the question was _Is the return statement what makes it go step by step back? Or something else?_ and not _what is the best linked list implementation to traverse it backwards?_

Comment: Luis see first line of question: "I was searching on how can I print a reverse of linked list and I found this piece of code". The issue of reverse ordering was the focus of his original problem. The issue of recursion was a fallout of this original problem and led to the question. I was simply pointing him to a simpler solution if this approach is causing him some consternation. Personally, I find (from experience) more general answers give helpful leads. If it is not welcome I'll take it down.

Comment: You are right in that complete general answers are better than simple or nongeneral ones.  But recursion is a general technique that must be studied also, even not being many times the best approach to a problem.  The first example in studying recursion is normally the factorial one, which no one solves by a recursive function in reality, and questions arise on that, but nobody answers it saying that recursion is something to be avoided. Not before having a good knowledge.

Comment: Luis I understand the analogy, but I recently answered a question regarding inline assembly and SIMD and AVX instructions. In part of my answering I mentioned the use of intrinsics. The questioner had no idea that these even existed and this changed his direction entirely. I always understood stackoverflow to be a resource for helping rather than just answering. As long as your answer is in the right context then it is a valid response even if it does not address the question directly. You're an expert but the questioner mightn't be. I'll leave this up for a week or so more. Then take it down.